# Numba gives a type error when compiling this trivial function

Tags: python, numpy, numba

When calling this function I get the following compilation error, but I can't figure out why:

```
from numba import njit
import numpy as np

@njit
def fubar(x: np.uint64):
    assert False 
    y = np.uint64(0)
    y = x
    y | 1
```

It seems to think `y` is a `float64` even though it's clearly a `uint64`, and therefore can't apply a bitwise operation to `y`. It doesn't give me a compilation error if I change references to `uint64` to `int64`. It also doesn't give me a compilation error if I remove the `assert False`.

```
> fubar(0)

TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
Invalid use of Function(<built-in function or_>) with argument(s) of type(s): (float64, Literal[int](1))
Known signatures:
 * (bool, bool) -> bool
 * (int64, int64) -> int64
 * (int64, uint64) -> int64
 * (uint64, int64) -> int64
 * (uint64, uint64) -> uint64
 * parameterized
In definition 0:
    All templates rejected with literals.
In definition 1:
    All templates rejected without literals.
In definition 2:
    All templates rejected with literals.
In definition 3:
    All templates rejected without literals.
In definition 4:
    All templates rejected with literals.
In definition 5:
    All templates rejected without literals.
This error is usually caused by passing an argument of a type that is unsupported by the named function.
[1] During: typing of intrinsic-call at <ipython-input-6-5336d5e671fe> (9)

File "<ipython-input-6-5336d5e671fe>", line 9:
def fubar(x: np.uint64):
    <source elided>
    y = x
    y | 1
    ^
```

I am using Kaggle's notebooks, which is currently running Python v3.7.6, Numpy v1.18.5, Numba v0.48.0.

Comment: I get no errors using the following: Windows 10, Jupyter Notebooks, Python 3.8.3 , Numpy 1.19.0, Numba 0.50.1.

Comment: same as @DarrylG

Comment: Thank you for confirming. I will post it to the issues section of Kaggle's [docker image](https://github.com/Kaggle/docker-python/issues/943).